# receive a responseText in ajax but without div tag

Tags: ajax

I want to know if there is any other way without using a div tag to receive response html when sending parameter whith ajax.
I'am asking because when I am building the select in other servlet and returning the result to jsp it receive the responsehtml in a div tag when we use the famous:

```
x = xhr.responseText;
document.getElementById('param').innerHTML = x;
```

with `param` is the id of div tag.
Note:   `<div id="param" style='display:inline'>`
this works fine when populating ddl but its constraint are multiple for my case.

Thinks.

Answer (score 0):

Give the id `param` to any element you want to use instead of the `div` and response will be shown in that element.

Comment: No I tried it whithout div tag and i give the id of the select tag but it did not work.
I think it is impossible without div tag.

Comment: So it's ok I found an other way. thinks for your answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct you don't want to have a dummy div element only to be able to place inside a html fragment received from ajax. In this case you can build you element directly and insert befor or after a real DOM element which you already have. The code can looks like following

```
jQuery('#select_id').remove(); // if not exists this line makes nothing
var htmlfragment = '<div id="select_id">';
htmlfragment += x; // place data with select element received from ajax call
htmlfragment += '</div>';
jQuery(htmlfragment).insertBefore("#myexistingelement");
```